# Submit simple form, loop and send mail?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a absolute PHP n00b, so i could use some help with a small snippet.

I have a simple form with a couple of radio and input fields. Once they are all filled and the user submits the form, i want to, via jQuery AJAX, submit it to a PHP file, which loops thorugh all the form elements in the request, adds them to a string, and sends that string as an email (with a predefined subject) to a predefined email account. How would you go about this simple task in PHP?

Comment: Can you post some of your codes?

Comment: That isn't a "small snippet". That's a significant number of distinct tasks split across multiple programming languages. Break it down into the different problems, then address them one at a time.

Comment: I dont need help with the form, input validation, jQuery AJAX submit etc. It is only the PHP snippet which loops through the form request and sends an email. Sorry if i was vague in my post.

Comment: Ok, may you post your jQuery/Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
<?php
$to = 'asdf@example.com';
$subject = 'website form';
$message= '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $message .= $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Comment: This line "foreach ($_POST as key => value)" fails with "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM.."? If i remove the foreach it works as expected :)

Comment: Should be: `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)`

Comment: Got it! Replaced it with "foreach ($_POST as $name => $value)" and that works. Thx!

Comment: sorry, I wrote too much c# and python in the past few days ;-)
I just corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// html_file.html
<form action="" method="POST">...</form>

<script>
$("form").on("submit", function()
{
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize());
});
</script>

// some_php_file.php
<?php
..
foreach ($_POST as $post_field) {} // process posted data
mail(..) //send mail
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = '';
$fields_to_place = array('name', 'message', 'phone', 'status');
foreach($fields_to_place as $f)
{
  if(isset($_POST[$f])) $message .= $f.': '.$_POST[$f]."\n";
}

$headers = "From: server@example.tld\r
Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
mail('recipient@email.com', 'Contact Form', $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script can be included in the php file which has the form or you can have a separate php file with the below code, the php file has to be mentioned in th action attribute of the form

```
    <?php
    $content= "First Name: ".$_POST['firstname']."\n";
    $content.= "Last Name: ".$_POST['lastname']."\n";   

    $to = "contactsus@test.com" ;               

            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $headers .= "Mailed-By: test.com\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";            

            $headers = 'From:'.$_POST['email']  . "\r\n" .'Reply-To:'.$_POST['email'] . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

            if(mail($to,'testsubject',$content,$headers)){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Thank you for contacting us.We will get back to you soon.");
                    window.location.href="index.php";
            </script>
            <?php
            }else{
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("mail not sent! Please try after some time!");
                    window.location.href="index.php";
            </script>
            <?php

            }
    ?>
```

Here in the content variable ($content) you can add the fields posted from the form as mentioned. In $to variable you can mention the address to which the mail has to be sent. This would be simpler than that of using jquery or AJAX