# How to send contact form info to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I have a small form but I'm not understanding how to send it to an email using PHP.  There seems to be different techniques.  If someone could just code my small form so I can analyze it and take it from there.  Thank you in advance!!!

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
                            <p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="dew02d@yahoo.com"  />
                                <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="test feedback"  />
                                <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="main.html"  />
                            </p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>First Name:
                                <input type="text" name="First Name" size="30" maxlength="30"
                                style="margin-left:27px"  />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Last Name:
                                <input type="text" name="Last Name" size="30" maxlength="30" 
                                style="margin-left:27px"  />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Phone Number:
                                <input type="text" name="Phone Number" size="30" maxlength="10"  
                                style="margin-left:5px" />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Email:
                                <input type="text" name="Email" size="30" maxlength="30"  
                                style="margin-left:59px" />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="margin-top:19px; margin-left:244px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
                            </p>

                        </form>
```

Comment: Are you looking for php's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) ?

Comment: `mail('to', 'subject', 'message', header);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

[Submit simple form, loop and send mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925768/submit-simple-form-loop-and-send-mail)

Only one thing,  set your to and subject in php

Ans set form action to this page.

This is best I found and you can use for any field in form.

Comment: it worked but when i submit the form, the browser displays the empty php document.  How do i get it to re-display the contact form webpage?